# qiskit.algorithms.optimizers callback function for all optimizers

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms, quantum-circuit, vqe, optimization

I am aware that VQE and VQC factory supports callback functions which can allow us to store intermediate values during optimization through callbacks in its arguments. However my loss function is custom-built and is not a simple average value of an operator as is what is required for the VQE factory. I would like to therefore use the optimizer.minimize() module to store the intermediate values (params, loss_function(params)) for different optimizers. Currently the set-up of my problem is as follows:

```
def Optimizer_routines(ansatz, optimizer_type, loss_function_computer, gradient_eval_method, initial_point):
    
    intermediate_info = {
    'parameters': [],   #VALS OF PARAMETERS
    'loss_function': []    # VALS OF LOSS FUNCTION
     }
    
    
    def callback(nfev, parameters, loss_function, **args):   #storing intermediate info
        intermediate_info['parameters'].append(parameters)
        intermediate_info['loss_function'].append(expectation_eval_method(parameters))
        print ("loss function", expectation_eval_method(parameters))
        
        
    if optimizer_type == 'vanilla_GD':   # supports callback
        optimizer = GradientDescent(maxiter=200, learning_rate=0.01, callback=callback)
        
    
    if optimizer_type == 'SPSA':         # supports callback
        optimizer =   SPSA(maxiter=1200, blocking=False, allowed_increase=None, trust_region=False,learning_rate=None, perturbation=None, 
last_avg=1, resamplings=1, perturbation_dims=None, second_order=False, regularization='ridge', hessian_delay=0, 
lse_solver=None, initial_hessian=None, callback=callback, termination_checker=None)
    

    if optimizer_type == 'COBYLA':  # does not support call back
        optimizer = COBYLA(maxiter=200, rhobeg=1.0, callback=callback)
    
    minimizer_object = optimizer.minimize( 
                        fun=loss_function_computer,  # function to minimize
                        jac=gradient_eval_method,  # function to evaluate the gradient
                        x0=initial_point)
return intermediate_info


def loss_function_computer(param_value_list):  "---> list of param values as args"
   " Loss function computer from different expectation vals from a circuit ansatz
     and returns a float for the loss function value"
   return value.real

def gradient_eval_method(param_value_list):  "---> list of param values as args"
    " Gradient computer from a circuit ansatz
     and returns a list of floats for the gradient of the entire parameter vector"
   return grad_list

initial_point = np.random.uniform(0,2*np.pi, circuit.num_parameters)
optimizer_type = 'COBYLA'
optimized_result_dict = Optimizer_routines(circuit, optimizer_type, loss_function_computer, gradient_eval_method, param_value_list)
```

Even though this method works fine for GradDescent and SPSA but it fails to deliver a callback for storing intermediary params during optimization for COBYLA, SLSQP, ADAM, L-BFGS_B etc. These optimizers do not have a callback in the args of its initializer.
Is there anyway to store the intermediary values (params, loss_function(params)) for these optimizers too ? Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: COBYLA. L_BFGS and SLSQP are based on scipy optimizers and for their callback signature check scipy.optimize.mimize. The callback signature is dependent on the optimizers but it should be supported for these. I do not believe the ADAM optimizer, as you say, supports a callback. BTW there is also a SciPyOptimizer, which is more general in Qiskit for these, which COBYLA etc extend but can be used directly.